# Unicode chars in console through C++

Tags: c++, unicode, console

Windows 8 x64;
Visual Studio 2012;

I learn C++ by book. On this forum I found [many themes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unicode%20console%20C%2b%2b&submit=search) about read\write Unicode strings through C++. But this themes not marked as solved(???). Is it really big problem in C++? I have tried different variants - they not working to me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // variant 1:
    wcout << L"Hello World!" << endl; // displayed
    wcout << L"Привет Мир!" << endl;// not displayed

    //**********************************************

    // variant 2:
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    wchar_t s[] = L"Hello World (2)!";
    int bufferSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, 
        s, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* m = new char[bufferSize]; 
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s, -1, m, 
        bufferSize, NULL, NULL);

    wprintf(L"%S", m); // valid output
    wcout << endl;
    printf("%s", m); // valid output
    wcout << endl;

    wchar_t s2[] = L"Привет мир (2)!";
    int bufferSize2 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, 
        s2, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* m2 = new char[bufferSize2]; 
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s2, -1, m2, 
        bufferSize2, NULL, NULL);

    wprintf(L"%S", m2); // invalid output
    wcout << endl;
    printf("%s", m2); // invalid output
    wcout << endl;
    //**********************************************

    // variant 3 (not working):
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"Testing unicode -- English -- Ελληνικά"
        << "-- Español." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it works for English chars only... 
Screen:

[image]

How can I solve it problem through C++?

Comment: Off topic, but how can you make windows 8's window corner curve like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the clearer decission then `chcp` command using:

```
// Getting the readable Cyrillic chars in the console window...
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
wcout << endl << L"Добро "; // UNICODE
cout << "пожаловать!" << endl; // ANSI
```

For both cases I get the readable output.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround for this is executing

> chcp 65001

in `cmd.exe` before executing your program (I don't know how to do that programmatically). 65001 is a magic value for UTF8 encoding. List of other code pages available for `chcp` is here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true . Other interesting value is 855 for Cyrillic CP1251.

And don't forget to switch the console font to Lucida (the default font does not work with UTf-8).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, before run my EXE file, but the result is same. :(((

Comment: @Bush I forgot to say you need to switch the console font to Lucida using `cmd.exe` Properties. I'd be glad to hear whether this does the trick.

Comment: <quote>And don't forget to switch your console font to Lucide</quote>
Yes, now it works! Thank you!

Comment: I believe `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` does in part the same thing as `chcp 65001`.

Comment: If you look up Boost.Nowide you can use that to get a nice fix.

Answer (score 2):

I found more simple variant (without changing of code page, and font):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Привет мир (1)!" << endl; // invalid output

    SetConsoleCP(GetACP());
    SetConsoleOutputCP(GetACP());

    cout<<"Привет мир (2)!" << endl; // valid output!

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it will interesting not for me only.

P.S. But... It works in CMD.EXE, but not works in POWERSHELL.EXE.

Answer (score -1):

Oh~~Forgive me, below is in C.

In C++ you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    locale::global(std::locale(""));
    wcout << L"Привет Мир!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);
```

The default setting is (LC_ALL,"C"). So you can't display characters other than ASCII codes

Comment: Thank you. I add it in my CPP file, rebuild it, but the result is same. :((( How this problem is solved by those who doesn't speak English?

Comment: Maybe there's some problem displaying unicode characters in cmd.exe because cmd doesn't fully support unicode